# CPU Intel Core i7-4790 PCI support

Tags: cpu, pci

I am planning to buy Intel Core i7-4790 and use it in combination with Asus Z97-AR motherboard. The motherboard has 2 PCI slots, will these be still working with the CPU?

The specs on Intel web site have details on the PCIe ports for the CPU, but PCI is not mentioned at all, which left me worried.

I have an old Creative X-FI PCI sound card, which I really love and don't want to lose the ability to use it.

Comment: If the motherboard supports your CPU then of course it will.

Comment: The CPU does not support PCI, but the motherboard/chipsset probably does.  (Neither did CPU's support PCI-e until recently).

Comment: So basically the PCI support only depends on the motherboard?

Comment: If the motherboard advertises a feature, then its going to work, provided you use a CPU that the motherboard supports.

Comment: The real question is there a driver for your OS and that card.

Comment: Yes, there is. I've already installed it with Windows 8 before my old motherboard died. It had problems with some additional software like "mode switcher", but the drivers are OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your motherboard uses is a "PCIe-PCI-bridge". Think of it as the high-performance version of a USB-Parallel printer adapter. It talks the newer language on one side, translating it to the older language on the other.

Many PCIe cards carry one of those on board. They consist of a PCI-based chip and a bridge to wire them to the new bus.

Long story short: It works reliably, and for whatever device finds enough bandwidth in a PCI slot, it won't have a problem.